# center environment nag-warning for floats in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, horizontal-alignment, warnings, nag

The `nag` packages gives a warning when using floats in beamer presentations. When removing the `figure` or `table` environment, no warnings are given. How to proceed from here? Tried `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, but that didn't work either.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{text}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could just not load nag. floating figures do not really make sense in a fixed page break slide context as in beamer, but it supports the syntax so you you can use it if you wish.

Comment: It's just a good old habit, loading `nag`, but I see your point.

Comment: just looking at nag now, you don't need to use `\centering` in beamer as the class redefines figure to use `\begin{center}` internally (which is why nag complains:-)

Comment: So one can not get rid of the warning at all, even if you remove `\centering`?

Comment: Not without redefining nag internals to remove the check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`beamer` adds `center` to `figure` which causes `nag` to complain whatever you do.

You could not load `nag` or if you want to load it you can stop it messing with `center`

```
\let\zcenter\center
\let\zendcenter\endcenter
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\let\center\zcenter
\let\endcenter\zendcenter

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{text}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I shortened it down to: `\let\zendcenter\endcenter\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}\let\endcenter\zendcenter`in the first line. That also did the job. Is that bad coding btw?

Comment: @TobiasDK Oh OK yes that works too, I had to experiment a bit to see exactly where nag was hooking in to things, stopped once I got something that worked, but simpler is good:-)